# "javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError" when implementing Jersey on Tomcat

Tags: java, linux, tomcat, jersey

When I tried to implement the method below on Tomcat on a Linux server using("sudo service tomcat7 start"), all the other methods work fine except this one.

```
@GET
    @Path("getapk")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
    public Response getApk() {
        System.out.println("GetApk!");
        final File apkFile = new File(apkFileLocation).listFiles()[0];
        return Response.ok(
                    new StreamingOutput() {
                        public void write(OutputStream output) throws IOException,
                        WebApplicationException {
                            output.write(Files.readAllBytes(apkFile.toPath()));
                        }
                    }
                ).header("Content-Disposition", ContentDisposition.type("attachment").fileName(apkFile.getName()).build())
                .build();
    }
```

What's weird is that when I "Run on server" in Eclipse, this method works fine.

Below are the error messages I got:

> HTTP Status 500 -
>
> type Exception report
>
> message
>
> description The server encountered an internal error () that prevented
>   it from fulfilling this request.
>
> exception
>
> javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   robertlee/resource/EcgCloudDatabase$1
>     com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:420)
>     com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:538)
>     com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:716)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722) root
>   cause
>
> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: robertlee/resource/EcgCloudDatabase$1
>     robertlee.resource.EcgCloudDatabase.getApk(EcgCloudDatabase.java:691)
>     sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>     sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
>     com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)
>     com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$ResponseOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:205)
>     com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
>     com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:302)
>     com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
>     com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
>     com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
>     com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
>     com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1511)
>     com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1442)
>     com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1391)
>     com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1381)
>     com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:416)
>     com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:538)
>     com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:716)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722) root
>   cause
>
> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   robertlee.resource.EcgCloudDatabase$1
>     org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1701)
>     org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1546)
>     robertlee.resource.EcgCloudDatabase.getApk(EcgCloudDatabase.java:691)
>     sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>     sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
>     com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)
>     com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$ResponseOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:205)
>     com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
>     com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:302)
>     com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
>     com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
>     com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
>     com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
>     com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1511)
>     com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1442)
>     com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1391)
>     com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1381)
>     com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:416)
>     com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:538)
>     com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:716)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722) note The
>   full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache
>   Tomcat/7.0.26 logs.
>
> Apache Tomcat/7.0.26

Please help, thanks so much....

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the jar containing the class `robertlee/resource/EcgCloudDatabase` in WEB-INF/lib and recreate your deployment.

Comment: Thanks, however, I have included all the jars needed in `tomcat7/webapps/EcgCloudDatabase/WEB-INF/lib`, and those jars are exactly the same as I used in eclipse

Comment: Then you might want to follow up on the `note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.26 logs.` bit.  There might be an underlying cause triggering this.